# How to store multi-dimensional data

Tags: python, django, django-models, data-storage

I am building a couple of web applications to store data using Django. This data would be generated from lab tests and might have up to 100 parameters being logged against time. This would leave me with an NxN matrix of data.

I'm struggling to see how this would fit into a Django model as the number of parameters logged may change each time, and it seems inefficient to create a new model for each dataset.

What would be a good way of storing data like this? Would it be best to store it as a separate file and then just use a model to link a test to a datafile? If so what would be the best format for fast access and being able to quickly render and search through data, generate graphs etc in the application?

In answer to the question below:

- It would be useful to search through datasets generated from the same test for trend analysis etc.
- As I'm still beginning with this site I'm using SQLite, but planning to move to full SQL as it grows

Comment: Will you need to query on specific parameters from those logs? Or only storage and retrieval of the whole data.

Comment: It would be useful to query specific fields in the logs yes

Comment: Perhaps you could use postgres' only HStoreField or the just released (1.9) JsonField with jsonb data type. You would have to ditch sqlite though

Comment: OK thanks I've just been looking at the docs on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/). Is there an advantage of using the HStoreField over an ArrayField?

Comment: They have different purposes. ArrayField is just an array so it doesn't have names for the values. With HStore, If each of your values has a specific meaning you could query directly something like: `..objects.filter(data__factor1='x')`. If the data is just a big matrix of numbers an array of arrays sounds better.

Comment: Looks good thanks. So my other idea was just to save the data as a csv and then use a `model.FileField` to point to it. I could then use a view to get this data out and display it. I guess that way would not be that efficient? Although I've found python can munch through csv files pretty quickly?

Comment: It might be enough if you don't need to filter the data. Otherwise, depending on the size of the CSV you'd need to index the data in some way (such as SQL database) for acceptable performance.